# manipulate 3rd party *.less css without hacking it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

In a Meteor (nodejs) project we use the less CSS preprocessor, and we use 3rd party "bootstrap-full.less" for our css styling.

There is one (maybe more) CSS rule in bootstrap that I would like to nuke, because it conditionally overrides other rules. (details below)

However, I don't want to "hack" the original bootstrap file, cause that is "vendor code".

I know I could re-override the CSS rules, but this is more work and hassle.

So the question is:
Is it possible to manipulate/process the parsed css rules in less before the actual css is generated?

---

In particular, there is this rule here,

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ...
  // Make all grid-sized elements block level again
  [class*="span"],
  .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
```

which is undesirable in my case, because we only have this on a sidebar, that keeps the same width even on mobile. So it should continue to behave like a table with cells (span1, span2 etc) being floated.

Ok, maybe I will figure out a different solution for my CSS / bootstrap problem, but still it would be interesting to know if less allows me to manipulate the css it produces.

Comment: You can override rules with !important

Comment: yes i know. But then I have to recreate all the .span1, .span2, .span3, .span4 etc dynamic grid widths, and other things. I'd have to rewrite a huge part of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in my project is create a master `.less` file and within that file import my third party less files and then following that my custom files. Any classes that you want to update, create a dupe `.less` file with that class in it in your own directory and then simply edit the properties you want to change in your files. So for example:

**master.less**

```
@import "/static/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

// My custom files

@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "type.less";
```

And then you have your own file called

**type.less**

```
h6{
    color: @myCustomColor;
}
```

This way you keep all the bootstrap files intact and only overwrite what you need to. It also keeps the files nicely seperated so it's easy to navigate and also a snap if you ever need to update the bootstrap source.

Comment: so you don't use bootstrap-full.less but separate ones? and then have your own version of those you want to override or nuke? ok, seems to be an option. thanks!

Comment: I downloaded their library straight from their github. In that they have all their styles separated out into different less files. If you are only planning on overriding one or two styles, just put those after the @import statement, no reason to create all new files, but my project includes a large portion of customization, so it makes it much more manageable.

Comment: The answer does not directly answer the question of processing 3rd party less code, but it is quite helpful anyway, so I vote it up! i will keep it open for a while so others can jump in, maybe there are other interesting replies.

Comment: I just found that this is exceptionally difficult in Meteor, because it always includes everything automatically. Any LESS @import would cause a duplicate.  
They are trying to fix this but this can take a while.

Comment: This is also the reason why my colleague chose the bootstrap-full.css, to not have so many separate css files in the browser.

Comment: Well, the browser wouldn't have any extra CSS files because LESS is all compiled beforehand (either server side or with a JS client compiler). If you have duplicate styles (which you shouldn't have many because your custom LESS files ONLY contain the styles you want to override) then when LESS compiles it it should simply overwrite any earlier ones with the latter styles.

Comment: The problem is with Meteor. If you put a LESS or CSS file anywhere in your project folders AND import it in another LESS file, then Meteor will add it as a regular CSS file in html head, AND Less will do the import - so you get it twice. They are planning to provide a way to have some files excluded, but right now this is not possible.